# How to start Emacs For Mac OS X from the command line without blocking?

Tags: macos, emacs

[A tip](http://emacsformacosx.com/tips) from the website of Emacs For Mac OS X suggests executing the following script to start it from the command line:

```
#!/bin/sh
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs "$@"
```

However, this will block the command line until Emacs.app exists.

Is there a way to start it from the command line without blocking?

Comment: If you add `&` to the end of the command, does it work?

Comment: @Chris It works, but I have to add `--chdir` argument to make relative paths work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally got it figured out:

```
#!/bin/sh
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs --chdir $PWD "$@" &
```

Or:

```
#!/bin/sh
open -a Emacs --args --chdir $PWD "$@"
```

The `--chdir` argument is necessary if we want to pass relative paths to Emacs.

I do not know if there are more idiomatic ways to do this though.

Comment: The solution based on `open` does not work if Emacs is already running.

Comment: I believe the issue is the use of the `--args` flag for `open`. Using `open -a Emacs "$1"` works, but doesn't allow passing arbitrary command-line arguments, which @Domon mentioned was needed in [another comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30677564/how-to-start-emacs-for-mac-os-x-from-the-command-line-without-blocking/30677813#comment49417005_30677700).

Comment: @LiberalArtist, depending on what behavior you are looking for, you can add the `-n` argument to `open` to use a new instance.  If you prefer a new buffer within an existing instance you will need to go the `emacsclient` route.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shell function I've used for years.  It'll start Emacs if it's not already running, otherwise it'll use the Emacs server to edit whatever file you pass to it in the existing copy of Emacs.  It works in a similar way to the command-line tools for other Mac editors like BBEdit, TextMate and Sublime Text.

```
e () {
    (
        (( $# == 0 )) && emacsclient -ne 1 || emacsclient -n $@ >&/dev/null
    ) || (
        launch -b ~/Applications/Emacs.app && until {
                emacsclient -n $@ >&/dev/null
            }
        do
            sleep 1
        done
    )
    export EDITOR=emacsclient
}
```

A few notes:

If you don't have `launch` installed (I wrote it, so I'm a bit biased :-) you can use `open -g` instead of `launch -b` — the idea is to start Emacs up in the background until it’s ready to be used.

If you don't have the Emacs server set to start up automatically with Emacs, you can either add `(server-start)` to your `~/.emacs` or customize `server-mode`.

You need to use the version of `emacsclient` that matches your Emacs, for example mine is `~/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/bin/emacsclient`.  (I just added `~/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/bin` to my `$PATH`).